# Console App Connection String Format Exception

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am adding a new console app to an existing EF Core ABP project.

During initialization I'm getting an exception when it's trying to parse the connectionstring from App.config.

The exception is:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0
```

It's reading app.config fine because if I change the name of the string from "Default" to something else is complains about not finding the default - as expected.

If I hardcode the connection string in during OnModeling in the context class in the EF project it works fine.

Any insight?

Comment: Could you please post your ConnectionString from config file?

Comment: Which DB are you trying to connect?

Answer (score 0):

you can override `DefaultConnectionStringResolver` > `GetNameOrConnectionString`

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/95b19dbce4a9785fdac1d6f5ca74fa16dd690eeb/src/Abp/Domain/Uow/DefaultConnectionStringResolver.cs#L35

PS: as you see in the source-code, when there's only 1 connection string ABP gets that. So **Default** config key is not crucial.